# How can I split strings with regex so that only numbers are selected

Tags: regular-expressions

examples

```
text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"#
```

How can I get with regex in Mathematica as results:

```
split_text1 = {'95', '85', '0.18', '4680'}

split_text2 = {'3', '80.0','0.0', '0.0', 0.0}
```

Comment: ``Select[NumericQ] /@ ImportString[text1, "Table"]``? Although this will fail to return $95$ because it is not separated by a space ...

Comment: `TextCases[text1, "Number"]` works for the first one but not the second. Are you committed to regex specifically or are other pattern matching solutions acceptable as well? In either case, is seems that `StringCases` would be the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680";
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00  .00000E+00 /";

R = RegularExpression["[+-]?\\d*(\\.\\d|\\d\\.|\\d)\\d*([eE][+-]?\\d+)?"];

getnumbers[s_String] := Interpreter["Number"]@StringCases[s, R]

getnumbers[text1]
(*    {95, 85, 0.18, 4680}    *)

getnumbers[text2]
(*    {3, 80., 0., 0., 0.}    *)
```

The regular expression is a bit complicated by the `(\\.\\d|\\d\\.|\\d)` alternatives: either we have a dot followed by a number, or a number followed by a dot, or just a number, but never just a dot alone. This allows matching `1.0`, `2.` and `.3` but not matching `.`.

Answer (score 6):

```
StringCases[text1, NumberString]
```

> ```
> {"95", "85", "0.18", "4680"}
> ```

For `text2` we need additional processing:

```
StringCases[{text1, text2}, 
  {n : NumberString ~~ "E" ~~ _ ~~ NumberString :>
     ToString @ Internal`StringToDouble[n], 
   NumberString}]
```

> ```
> {{"95", "85", "0.18", "4680"}, {"3", "80.", "0.", "0.", "0."}}
> ```